# Preventing tar from using too much CPU and disk (old laptop crashes if 100%)

Tags: tar, limit

I want to backup 1 terabyte of data to an external disk.

I am using this command: `tar cf /media/MYDISK/backup.tar mydata`

PROBLEM: My poor laptop freezes and crashes whenever I use 100% CPU or 100% disk *(if you want to react about this please [write here](https://superuser.com/questions/304421/thinkpad-cpu-temperature-reaches-100c-after-10-minutes-of-heavy-use))*.
So I want to stay at around 50% CPU and 50% disk max.

My question: How to throttle CPU and disk with the `tar` command?

Rsync has a --bwlimit option, but I want an archive because 1) there are many small files 2) I prefer to manage a single file rather a tree. That's why I use `tar`.

Comment: What a clever idea to make such huge tarball :DDD What about 'nice' command?

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha: `nice` will not prevent 100% CPU usage

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) to throttle the bandwidth of a pipe. Since your use case is strongly IO-bound, the added CPU overhead of going through a pipe shouldn't be noticeable, and you don't need to do any CPU throttling.

```
tar cf - mydata | pv -L 1m >/media/MYDISK/backup.tar
```

Comment: Even better than what I was expecting! I am limiting IO to 5mb/second and the CPU stays at 13% (seems reasonable with encryption going on).

Comment: Very nice!. Maybe also recommend the -q flag to eliminate the progress bar.

Comment: such a great command!!! If you don't have it in your Debian/Ubuntu, just run `apt-get install pv`.  
I recommend adding ` -b ` after `-L 1m`: this way an incremental byte counter will be printed, updated every second. In this way you know how many bytes have been written until now

Comment: Also, please note that if you compress output (using `tar czf` instead of `tar cf`) the limit refers to the compressed output (so with `-L 1m` your disk write will not exceed 1 MB/s....but your disk read will be probably between 1 MB/s and 5 MB/s, depending on your content type)

Comment: Great trick ! When compressing with xz, I pipe through pv first then through xz.

Answer (score 8):

You can try the [cpulimit tool](https://github.com/opsengine/cpulimit) which does limit the CPU percentage. It is not a standard tool, so you will have to install it. Here is a quick excerpt of the README:

> "Cpulimit is a tool which attempts to limit the CPU usage of a process
>   (expressed in percentage, not in CPU time). [...] The control of the
>   used cpu amount is done sending SIGSTOP and SIGCONT POSIX signals to
>   processes. All the children processes and threads of the specified
>   process will share the same percent of CPU."

Then I would recommend ionice for limiting the IO usage, though it is the concurrent access that would be limited, not the maximum throughput... Never-the-less here is how to use it:

```
ionice -c 3 <your_command>
```

Comment: Great! It seems like cpulimit is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really get a process to run *less*. You can use `nice` to give it a lower priority, but that's in relation to other processes. The way to run the CPU cooler while a process runs is to use `usleep(3)` to force the process out of the run state a certain amount of time, but that would involve either patching `tar` or using the `LD_PRELOAD` mechanism to provide a patched function that `tar` uses a lot (e.g. `fopen(3)`).

I suspect your best workarounds are the hardware ones you've mentioned on SuperUser: keeping the laptop cool and/or lowering the CPU clock.

An annoying but possibly viable workaround (a kludge, really) works at a ‘macroscopic’ level. Rather than making `tar` run 100ms every 200ms, you could make it run one second out of every two. Note: this is a horrible, horrible kludge. But hey, it might even work!

```bsh
tar cjf some-file.tar.bz2 /some-directory &
while true; do
    sleep 1  # Let it run for a second
    kill -STOP $! 2>/dev/null || break
    sleep 1  # Pause it for a second
    kill -CONT $! 2>/dev/null || break
done
```

The first `sleep` adjusts sleep time, the second one adjusts runtime. As it stands now, it's got a 50% duty cycle. To keep the temperature down, you will very likely need to reduce the duty cycle to perhaps 25% or lower (1 second run, 3 seconds sleep = 1 of every 4 seconds = 25% duty cycle). The shell command `sleep` can take fractional times, by the way. So you could even say `sleep 0.1`. Keep it over 0.001 just to be sure, and don't forget that script execution adds to the time too.

Comment: +1 Nice idea! I guess it is similar to the cpulimit tool Huygens suggests.

Comment: Except Huuygens' tool is much better and more practical, which is why that answer got my own +1. :)

Answer (score 0):

A more general purpose way of limiting the CPU is to use `/sys`. This seems like what you want anyway since things other than `tar` are capable of performing computationally expensive tasks, its just that youre seeing `tar` do it the most.

The way to do this is to:

1. go to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/cpufreq` for each of your CPUs (replace `cpuX` with each cpu).
2. Then look in the file `scaling_available_frequencies` to see what frequencies your CPU supports.
3. Pick a frequency (lets say 1234567) and do `echo 1234567 > scaling_max_freq`

This will prevent the CPU from ever going above the specified frequency.

Comment: Thanks, but I am already at the lowest possible frequency. I should have mentioned that. I started underclocking as soon as these problems began appearing.