# Linux equivalent of Windows Power options, specifically processor management

Tags: power-management, software-rec

I am looking for some sort of power management for my old laptop which is running openSUSE Leap. I want to set up maximum usage of processor to 50% or even less. In Windows this is easy with a couple of clicks, but in Linux I couldn't find a proper app to handle this.

Comment: Writing to a certain file is OK? Something like `echo 50 > /sys/…`?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39722/41515

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your goal.

- If you want to restrict a **program's access to the processor**, try [cpulimit](https://github.com/opsengine/cpulimit) or [cgroups](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-cpu.html). Cgroups is much more powerful. It also allows IO limits and limiting entire groups of processes.
- You might really just want to prioritize a program, using nice (and possibly ionice).
- If you want to keep your **system cool**, you may wish to throttle the processor for all programs or use tools such as powertop.