# Limit tar read speed

Tags: linux, tar, disk, io

I'm using `tar` do make backups of a machine. But, it is using a lot of I/O and slows down the whole machine.

So, is there a way to limit the **read** speed of `tar`?

I know about `pv`, but it limit only the **write** speed. Because I do incremental backups with `tar --listed-incremental`, this will work only with the first full backup (subsequent incremental backups will then consume a lot of read I/O if there is only small changes).

I've tried to lower the overall priority of the backup with a combination of `nice` and `ionice`, but this not really change anything.

Informations: it's Debian 9 machine, and the files are residing on an ext4 file-system on top of a LVM volume.

Comment: As a side note, sorry if I'm not posting the question on the right website. I'm a bit confused about the difference between unix.stackexchange, Super User and Server Fault since this question seems to be on-topic for these 3 websites.

Comment: check out cpulimit as in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39730/3375

Comment: Have you tried limiting the *output* of `tar` using something like `pv`, as you mentioned?

Comment: Be careful, `gtar` in general is unable to restore it's incremental backups. This only works in case that the differences between two incrementals are trivial and do not include renamed directories.

Comment: For completeness -and for tips for us noobs- can you include how you can use pv to limit the output rate? (edit: ah, rtfm... its in https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv)

Answer (score 2):

You can run your tar command using `ionice`. Like this:

```
ionice -c3 tar --listed-incremental [...]
```

This will let the `tar` process only do I/O when there is no other process waiting for I/O.

In Debian the `ionice` utility is in the package `util-linux`, so you you may need to install that first.

Like with the normal (cpu) `nice` utility, the I/O scheduler class of a process is inherited by its child processes. When I'm planning to do resource-heavy stuff, I do not want users have their I/O slowed down because of it. I often start my shell this way:

```
nice ionice -c3 bash
```

Then everything I do from that shell will be very, very nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Use cgroups

```
mkdir -p /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/g1
echo "8:0 1048576" > /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/g1/blkio.throttle.read_bps_device
pgrep -f tar > /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/g1/cgroup.procs
```

https://andrestc.com/post/cgroups-io/